# angularjs compile function problems in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning how to make directives and I am trying to make a custom table pagination directive (I know there are existing ones out there, but I am choosing to make my own). This directive so far figures out how many rows there are in the table (not counting nested tables/rows) so that it can use that to separate the table when I get to the actual pagination.  It also figures out how wide the table is in columns so it knows where to put the page numbers (bottom right of the table).  I send in data to the directive to tell it how many results per page should be in the table (tAttrs.defaultPageLength).  It seems to do all the math correctly and even make the array with the page numbers in it correctly, but when it uses the pageNumbers array in the ng-repeat in the template below it never changes from two pages.  I console.log(pageNumbers) and it changes like it is supposed to based on how many items per page the user wants. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thank you in advance.

```
var myApp = angular.module("mainModule");
myApp.directive("paginateTable", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        compile: function (tElem, tAttrs, transclude) {
            tAttrs.defaultPageLength = tAttrs.defaultPageLength === undefined ? 5 : Attrs.defaultPageLength;
            console.log(tAttrs.defaultPageLength);

            var rowCount = ($(tElem).find(' > * > tr:last').index() + 1);       //how many rows are in main table (excluding any rows in nested tables)
            var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(rowCount / tAttrs.defaultPageLength);
            var showEnds = tAttrs.showEnds;
            var pageNumbers = [];
            var max = 0;

            $(tElem).find('*').children('tr').each(function () {        //find the number of columns in the main table
                var count = $(this).children('td').length;
                if (count > max) {
                    max = count;
                }
            });

            for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {              //create an array of page numbers for use in the ng-repeats down below in the HTML
                pageNumbers.push(i);
            }

            console.log(pageNumbers);

            if (showEnds === 'true') {
                $(tElem).find(' > * > tr:last').after('<tr><td colspan="' + (max - 1) +
                '"></td><td><div class="btn-group"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">First</button>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="pageNumber in pageNumbers">{{pageNumber}}</button>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Last</button> </div></td></tr > ');
            } else {
                $(tElem).find(' > * > tr:last').after('<tr><td colspan="' + (max - 1) +
                '"></td><td><div class="btn-group"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"' +
                'ng-repeat = "pageNumber in pageNumbers">{{pageNumber}}</button> </div></td></tr >');
            }

            return function (scope, element, attrs) {

            }

        }
    }
});
```

This is the HTML side:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <table id="pageTable" class="table" paginate-table show-ends="true" default-page-length="6">
                    <tr>
                        <th>heading 1</th>
                        <th>heading 2</th>
                        <th>heading 3</th>
                        <th>heading 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>entry 1</td>
                        <td>entry 2</td>
                        <td>entry 3</td>
                        <td>entry 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>entry 1</td>
                        <td>entry 2</td>
                        <td>entry 3</td>
                        <td>entry 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>entry 1</td>
                        <td>entry 2</td>
                        <td>entry 3</td>
                        <td>entry 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>entry 1</td>
                        <td>entry 2</td>
                        <td>entry 3</td>
                        <td>entry 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>entry 1</td>
                        <td>entry 2</td>
                        <td>entry 3</td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        test1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        test2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        test3
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        test4
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to assign the value of the local variable pageNumbers to the scope in the link function so that {{pageNumber}} in the ng-repeat would have something to reference.  Before it was referencing a variable with the same name which was on the parent controller (which is why the number of pages never changed no matter what I did to the variable in the directive).  Once I removed that variable from the parent controllers scope, and assigned pageNumbers to scope.pageNumbers in the link function it works properly.